# Vue.js computed value never run on startup

Tags: javascript, vue.js

My computed values get function is never run when the vm is created, so the value it should have is never assigned.

Strangely enough it's run if I try to access the value, it is just never run when the app starts.

Basically I'm supposed to be computing the value of the skin and on startup or when changed the stylesheet link should be altered to load the correct skin.

It works great, the problem is that it's not being run on startup. Do I have to use some hacky solution, like, getting the value once in the mounted function of the vm? Or am I missing something here...

```
    computed: {
        skin: {
            get: function () {
                var mySkin = "my/skin/string";
                if (window.localStorage.getItem("skin") === null) {
                    window.localStorage.setItem("skin", mySkin);
                    jquery("link[id='skin']").attr("href", "css/skins/" + mySkin + ".css");
                } else {
                    mySkin = window.localStorage.getItem("skin");
                    window.localStorage.setItem("skin", mySkin);
                    jquery("link[id='skin']").attr("href", "css/skins/" + mySkin + ".css");
                }
                var hey = this.skin;
                return mySkin;
            },
            set: function (val) {
                window.localStorage.setItem("skin", val);
                jquery("link[id='skin']").attr("href", "css/skins/" + val + ".css");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Computed property is a property which depends on data properties.

In your case it is better IMO to create a `data` property `skin`, and a method like `setSkin()` which initializes the `skin` data property, and another method `saveSkin()` to save your property into localStorage.

You then can run `setSkin()` in `mounted()` hook.

Template:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    skin: ''
  },
  methods: {
    setSkin: function() {
      this.skin = ...;
    },
    saveSkin: function() { // call this function when you need to save skin data into localStorage
      window.localStorage.setItem("skin", this.skin);
      ....
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.setSkin(); // retrieve skin data from localStorage, etc.
  }
});
```

Comment: This is almost exactly the same as having a computed value for the skin with a setter and a getter, but with setter/getter I'd have set and save in the same function, and the getter returns the current value. The question is more 'why doesn't my computed value get computed at startup' and I'm suspecting the answer is 'because nothing is trying to get it'. I thought computed values get computed once upon startup but it seems computed values are basically null values until something gets them, which isn't a huge problem it's just that my setter needs to be run upon startup so I need togetitonce.